# UItableViewCell issue

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios7

I am using `UItableViewController` and I add label to the cell programatically , the label reads data from `json` array , on scrolling the cell reuse and the label data change ,
there is any way to prevent this issue ?

Comment: Show a piece of code you're talking about.

Comment: Prevent this issue ? What issue ?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not clear.!! but according to your problem you might not set proper value(array count) for

```
    -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

and find the exact index in array using "indexPath.row"

```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

if you provide your code what you've written may help us to re correct it

Answer (score 0):

use following way :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

NSString *CellId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CellId%d%d",indexPath.row,indexPath.section];

if (!cell) 
{
    cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellId] autorelease];
}

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use this like of code.It is used to reload the data.

cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellId];